# Seeking sum of two squares reference

Tags: nt.number-theory

I need a reference to the fact that if a number can be the sum of two squares in four different ways, e.g.,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
w = u_1^2 + v_1^2\\
w = u_2^2 + v_2^2\\
w = u_3^2 + v_3^2\\
w = u_4^2 + v_4^2\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
the variables can always be parameterized as follows:
$w = (r^2 + R^2)(s^2 + S^2)(t^2 + T^2)$, 
$u_1 = ( rst + rST + RsT - RSt)$,
$v_1 = (-rsT + rSt + Rst + RST)$,
$u_2 = $, etc etc

Could anyone please supply a reference?  Many thanks.

Comment: i did some preliminary TeX editing; please edit the rest of your question using TeX, so that it is consumable---else no one might feel like reading it...

Comment: Why do you believe this to be true if you do not have a reference? (Where else have you seen it?) This appears to me related to Jacobi's theorem on representations as the sum of four squares, but I don't think what you have written is true...

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "etc etc"? I would like to see the question in full detail.

Comment: (To Suvrit et al, apologies, I don't have TeX on the machine I'm using right now, so thanks for your edit)  Hi GH, the full parametrization is w = (r2 + R2)*(s2 + S2)*(t2 + T2)
u1 = ( rst + rST + RsT - RSt)  
v1 = (-rsT + rSt + Rst + RST)
u2 = ( rst + rST - RsT + RSt)
v2 = ( rsT - rSt + Rst + RST)
u3 = ( rst - rST + RsT + RSt)
v3 = ( rsT + rSt - Rst + RST)
u4 = (-rst + rST + RsT + RSt)
v4 = ( rsT + rSt + Rst - RST)

Comment: @TimRoberts: Do you know a proof that every solution is given by your formulas?  If so, then what is your proof?

Comment: Hi Michael, I believe it to be true that every solution is given by this parametrization, but I don't have a simple proof, hence my urgently seeking a reference...

Comment: What do you mean by "different"? Is $2^2+1^2$ different from $1^2+2^2$? from $2^2+(-1)^2$?

Comment: Tim: (A) what is your background in mathematics? (B) where did you get this?

Comment: Hi Will, (a) BSc(Hons) in Maths 30 years ago, mainly a very part-time amateur since then. (b)I can claim no credit for this, I think it was from a correspondent on the Unsolved Problems group at unsolvedproblems dot org that I maintain, but I can no longer find the relevant message...Hi Greg, all of the variables are distinct positive integers....

Comment: @TimRoberts: it should be possible to answer your question by using the fact that $\mathbf{Z}[i]$ is a unique factorization domain (where $i^2=-1$).  Many people here (and more at math.stackexchange.com) would be happy to show you all the details.

Answer (score 4):

**The question**, as clarified by the OP in a comment, can be formulated as follows. Suppose that $w\in\mathbb{Z}$ factors in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ in four ways as
$$ w=(u_k+iv_k)(u_k-iv_k),\qquad u_k,v_k\in\mathbb{Z},\qquad k=1,2,3,4. $$
Then is it true that we can further factor these factors $u_k\pm iv_k$ as:
$$ u_1+iv_1=(r+iR)(s+iS)(t-iT),\quad u_1-iv_1=(r-iR)(s-iS)(t+iT), $$
$$ u_2+iv_2=(r+iR)(s-iS)(t+iT),\quad u_2-iv_2=(r-iR)(s+iS)(t-iT), $$
$$ u_3+iv_3=(r-iR)(s+iS)(t+iT),\quad u_3-iv_3=(r+iR)(s-iS)(t-iT), $$
$$ u_4+iv_4=-(r-iR)(s-iS)(t-iT),\quad u_4-iv_4=-(r+iR)(s+iS)(t+iT) ?$$

**The answer** is no. This is because the above equations imply that
$$ \prod_{k=1}^4 (u_k+iv_k) = -(r^2+R^2)^2(s^2+S^2)^2(t^2+T^2)^2 = - w^2,$$
while it is possible to find factorizations where this product is very different. For example, in the special case when $u_3+iv_3=u_1-iv_1$ and $u_4+iv_4=u_2-iv_2$, the considered product equals $w^2$.

**Just for the fun of it**, if we have two factorizations
$$ w=(u_k+iv_k)(u_k-iv_k),\qquad u_k,v_k\in\mathbb{Z},\qquad k=1,2, $$
then it is true that we can further factor these factors $u_k\pm iv_k$ as:
$$ u_1+iv_1=(r+iR)(s+iS),\qquad u_1-iv_1=(r-iR)(s-iS), $$
$$ u_2+iv_2=(r+iR)(s-iS),\qquad u_2-iv_2=(r-iR)(s+iS). $$
This can be proved in many ways, e.g. by Theorem 90 applied in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Comment: So, just to make sure I understand correctly, the parametrization I described does not produce all possibilities?

Comment: @Tim: Correct. It is hard to produce a generalization to four factorizations of my "just for fun" section for two factorizations. At any rate, finding all factorizations is easy and standard from the prime factorization of $w$ in Gaussian integers. I recommend you to read the relevant parts of Hardy-Wright: An introduction to the theory of numbers.

Comment: May I ask one final question, before the question is closed? Is the parametrization complete if w is itself a square?  That is, in the original post, w is replaced by w^2?

Comment: @Tim: The proof shows that the parametrization is incomplete for any positive integer $w$ that is a sum of two squares. In particular, it is incomplete when $w$ is any nonzero square number.